# XML parsing using XML::LibXML

Tags: xml, perl, xml-namespaces, xml-libxml

Here is the Sample data that am trying to parse to extract attribute value corresponding to node Company : CID, Name, Symbol, Value for all the Company nodes under Companies node

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StockRecords xmlns="http://url1"
              xmlns:ref="http://url2"
              xmlns:xsi="http://url3">
  <Companies>
    <Company>
      <CID>123</CID>
      <Name>Google</Name>
      <Symbol>GOOG</Symbol> 
      <Value>1234</Value>
    </Company>
  </Companies>
</StockRecords>
```

Following are the 2 variants that I tried.
**Variant 1**

```
use XML::LibXML;

my $filename = "test.xml";
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $filename);

foreach my $sample ($dom->findnodes( '/Companies/Company' )) {

    print Dumper($sample);
    last;
}
```

**Variant 2:** Since there are namespaces involved in it, XPathContext to be specified.

```
use XML::LibXML;

my $filename = "test.xml";
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xmldoc = $parser->parse_file($filename);

my $root = $xmldoc->getDocumentElement;

my @l = $root->getElementsByTagName('StockRecords');

my $xc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($root);

$xc->registerNs("ns1", "http://url1");
$xc->registerNs("ref", "http://url2");
$xc->registerNs("xsi", "http://url3");
```

Am not able to extract data for any attribute for the node. I did take a look at other answers, LibXML documentation still there is something am missing. Please help me with some pointers. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use XML::LibXML               qw( );
use XML::LibXML::XPathContext qw( );

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => $ARGV[0] );

my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new();
$xpc->registerNs( ns1 => "http://url1" );

for my $company_node ($xpc->findnodes("/ns1:StockRecords/ns1:Companies/ns1:Company", $doc)) {
   say $xpc->findvalue("ns1:CID", $company_node);
   say $xpc->findvalue("ns1:Name", $company_node);
}
```

Comment: Exactly this is what I was looking for, thanks.

There is a small modification in the source

Instead of 
<Symbol>GOOG</Symbol>

it would be,
<Symbol type="NASDAQ">GOOG</Symbol>

How to parse the 'type' attribute from the xml node?